# Empathy "Authentication failed" when connecting to Freenode

Tags: 12.04, empathy, irc

I have set up an IRC account in Empathy - the default server is, of course, Freenode. Empathy tries to connect and after a few moments reports, "Authentication failed".

I have tried with and without a password (My nickname is registered with Freenode.).

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

[image]

**Update:**

I was able to connect when on another network. Could the problem be with my Verizon Mobile Broadband?

Comment: I don't see a reason why there should be a problem with Verizon and Freenode. One thing I would try is to connect to Freenode via some other app, an IRC client at best. X-Chat, Quassel, WeeChat, smuxi or irssi for example.

Comment: Mrokii, the problem just disappeared.  0_o I'm now able to connect to Freenode, and I don't know of anything I changed. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Great that it works now. Hopefully it stays that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly that username is already registered with freenode and therefore secured with a password. Have you checked if you can connect by using another nickname?

Comment: Mrokii, I changed the username to something unique, but still had the same problem. I'm beginning to suspect my ISP. Please see the edit to my question. Thanks!